# Brief Idea about servlets

Tags: java, servlets

Where can I get knowledge about servlets?

Answer (score 8):

Most people would start with Sun's official tutorial about servlets.

http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html

Answer (score 6):

Background [from Jacob]:

Servlets are server side java programs. For example when you submit a order to buy some stuff a servlet could process your order and send you an email confirmation.

Servlets handle requests better than say CGI and most other technologies.

Servlets need a web container or a J2EE container to be able to deploy, your normal http server will not be sufficient.

Servlets are backed by the java programming language and as such programming languages theoretically have no limitations on delivering functionality, this is not true of some other languages

General Information

- [Java/Sun's information on it](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/)
- [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet)

Sun's Tutorials

- [Tutorial 1](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets.html)
- [Tutorial 2](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html)

Books

- [Head First Servlet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516681)

Answer (score 3):

After reading the official tutorial. Think of getting a copy of [Head First Servlet and JSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516681). Servlet and related techs would become handy after reading this.

Comment: +1 - Head First Servlets and JSP is the best book on Servlets. It is too good.

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are server side java programs. For example when you submit a order to buy some stuff a servlet could process your order and send you an email confirmation.

Servlets handle requests better than say CGI and most other technologies.

Servlets need a web container or a J2EE container to be able to deploy, your normal http server will not be sufficient.

Servlets are backed by the java programming language and as such programming languages theoretically have no limitations on delivering functionality, this is not true of some other languages.