# Struts 2 add an action to struts.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

I want to add an action to my `struts.xml` but when I do it my webapp stop to work and I don't know why. I post here some details of my webapp.

`web.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ILIMobileLeborgne</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`struts.xml` (in the src folder in Eclipse):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ilimobile" />

<package name="ilimobile" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="index">
        <result>/index.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="registerIllimite">
        <result>/registerIllimite.jsp</result>
    </action>

      <!-- When i try to do add the following action my app doesn't working, the browser said me that the ressource asked is unavailable and when i delete it my (little) app works correctly -->
    <action name="registerClientInfo"  class="action.SubscribeAction">
        <result name="success">/paiement.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>

</struts>
```

my SubscribeAction (in the action package in the source folder) :

```
package action;

import model.*;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class SubscribeAction extends ActionSupport {
private Client client;
private String abonnement;

public String getAbonnement() {
    return abonnement;
}

public void setAbonnement(String abonnement) {
    this.abonnement = abonnement;
}

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return SUCCESS;
}

public Client getClient() {
    return client;
}

public void setClient(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
}
}
```

And my JSP page which use the action defined :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<s:form action="registerClientInfo">
    <s:textfield key="client.nom"/>
    <s:textfield key="client.prenom"/>
    <s:textfield key="client.email"/>
    <s:textfield key="client.adresse"/>
    <s:textfield key="client.ville"/>
    <s:textfield key="client.cp"/>

    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you need some extra info ask me but i think you could see why my app doesn't want to work :/ I'm pretty sure that it's just a little error but i can't find it...

Thanks for all and have a happy new year party :)

(Sorry for my English I'm a french student ^^)

Edit : I post here the Eclipse stack trace which show me that he can't find my action class but i don't know why :/ I've a struts example made by my teacher and i don't think that he made some extra steps to deploy the app with a tomcat server on Eclipse

The stack trace :

```
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/home/blackmario/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ILIMobileLeborgne/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:20:68
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


Caused by: Action class [action.SubscribeAction] not found - action - file:/home/blackmario/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ILIMobileLeborgne/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:20:68
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:480)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:424)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:541)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:290)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: what is the url you typed?

Comment: It's just the base url of the app which is `http://localhost:8080:ILIMobileLeborgne/`, when i delete the last action under my comment my app works fine and if i uncomment it it's impossible to access any part of my app, my browser always says that the ressource is unavailable :/

Comment: Try this , localhost:8080/ILIMobileLeborgne/registerClientInfo

Comment: It's the same thing :/ The strange part is that when i add the action in the struts.xml, it blocks all part of my app not just the action that i've added :( I try to restart from scratch my project 2 or 3 times but it's always the same...

Comment: show me your application context

Comment: How can i show you that ?

Comment: The web server will show an error in the logs when starting up, can you please post that? A couple things to try, if it is xml related try deleting the comment block and retyping (not copying and pasting) once I had an issue with a hidden character. Check the paths, check where the web app is deployed and that the class and the jsp are where you expect them. Neither the class or the content of the jsp should be able to cause the issue (only if the action did not support the right signature for execute() there could be an issue but that is not the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it sounds like your application fails to start when you add that action, correct?  Nothing works, even the ones that worked before.  So, you should look in the logs of the servlet container you are using. Nothing is more fundamental that finding where the logs are and becoming familiar with them.

When you do look in the logs, I'm guessing you'll see either

1) an error complaining that the syntax of the struts.xml is bad and the application fails when trying to parse it.

or

2) A ClassNotFoundException because the class file for that action is not on the classpath of the application.  If this is the case make sure that the class files for that action are actually being put into the WAR file's WEB-INF/lib or WEB-INF/classes direcgtory; that's where a webapp's classloader looks for class files.  If you don't know much about this, you should read more about [Java Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704313/brief-idea-about-servlets).

Both of these are things that might cause the application to not successfully start.  You must look at the logs; they will amost always tell you that the application had a specific issue.  If you ask about that specific issue on this forum, you'll get very useful answers.  Otherwise, I'm kind of guessing.

Comment: I look at the logs and i saw that my action class SubscribeAction was not found ! So the web can't start properly but i don't know how to fix the problem, i followed some tutorial on the struts website et they use ant to compil classes but i don't know if it is required or if we can make the app without it :/ (because it's a study project and i'm not allowed to use this sort of tools)

Comment: I'm editing the answer to add a bit more reference, but it sounds like you need to research some java and java servlet basics.

Comment: Also, since I correctly diagnosed your problem, you might consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: @BlackMario You will have to make sure that the action class gets compiled and that the output .class file is added to the classes directory of your WEB-INF directory (following the proper package structure), then only would the server be able to find the action class.

Answer (score 0):

By default `.action` extension is used by the `struts-default` package that you extend. When you place the `url` in the browser make sure you have use correct `url`.

Comment: I've also tried with .action extension because i don't modify it but it doesn't work at all, add the action with the class SubscribeAction crash my app and i can't access to any part of my app :/ Maybe i can send you a .war so you could see the problem by yourself ? It could be more efficient to explain the problem instead of some sentences :/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<action name="registerClientInfo"  class="action.SubscribeAction">
    <result name="success">/paiement.jsp</result>
</action>
```

to

```
<action name="registerClientInfo"  class="SubscribeAction">
    <result name="success">/paiement.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Why?  The SubscribeAction is in the action package.